# "Changes to calendar" vs. "Changes in calendar"

Tags: prepositions

There's this section on a concert hall website where they inform people if their shows have been cancelled or rescheduled.

Is it correct to call this section

> Changes to calendar

or should it be called

> Changes in calendar

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Changes in" , "Changes of" or "Changes to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405625/changes-in-changes-of-or-changes-to)